# Problem when using return key to move to TDBGrid from TEdit

Tags: delphi

In a search form I have two components, a `TEdit` and and `TDBGrid`.   The user enters text into the `TEdit`and in the `TEdit.OnChange` event I search for matching items in a table using a query. These are displayed in a `TDGrid`.  The event only triggers when the user has entered more than three characters in the `TEdit.Text`to cut down the overhead.

The problem occurs when the search has returned all possible records and the user wants to select one of the records displayed in the `TDBGrid`.  While I told the users to use the `Tab` key (or the mouse) to switch from the `TEdit` to the `TDBGrid`, they use the return key to do this in another application and are insisting that they should be able to do the same thing in the application I'm altering/adding to.  I can understand this, but the problem is that if I use

```
if (key = VK_RETURN) then key := VK_TAB;
```

in the `TEdit.OnKeyUp` event, the original value of the last key pressed in the `TEdit` is "remembered" as `VK_RETURN` and is passed to the `TDBGrid`'s `OnKeyUp` event.  Since I have other actions triggered in that event, I get undesired things happening as soon the the `TDBGrid` gains focus because they also want to select the correct row in the grid by pressing the return key again.

Therefore what I want to do is to "cancel" the key value passed to the `TDBGrid` from the `TEdit`. I tried using `if (Sender = TEdit) then Key := VK_CANCEL;` in the `DGBrid`'s `OnKeyUp` event but I get a compiler "Incompatible types" error and I can't find anything to tell me how I should use it in this situation.

Is this possible?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following approach satisfies your needs and I suspect it to be the shortest such approach:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
    Key := #0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;
```

This will make <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in `Edit1`, move focus to the next control. This is accomplished by posting the form a `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message. The `OnKeyPress` handler is needed to suppress the "invalid input" message beep.

For bonus points, do

```
PostMessage(Handle, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, Ord(ssShift in Shift), 0);
```

instead to have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> correspond to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I'm not quite sure I like this entire idea, though. I think I prefer to have <kbd>Enter</kbd> act on key down instead. The target control shoudn't care about this key up message.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that works a treat.   I put the Edit1.OnKeyUp code into Edit1.OnKeyDown as you suggested.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to Andreas answer, I have used the same approach.  There are 3 events you can play around with, onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup.  At some point you will probably have to assign the key to null to avoid the "beep".  The other thing to watch out for are unintended side effects, like moving 2 fields instead of one as has happened to me in the past.

Comment: I don't see this as adding any value. You've basically just agreed with Andreas and provided no information not already provided in Andreas' answer, including the information about *assigning the key to null to avoid the "beep"*. This space is to be used to provide an answer to the question, not just comment on another answer.

Comment: I would have preferred adding a comment but not enough reputation.

Comment: You can't use the answer space to bypass not having the comment privilege. This space is ONLY for answering the question asked.

Comment: It was never my intention to "bypass" the comment privilege.

Comment: But your non-answer is still here, even after you've been made aware that it shouldn't be.

Comment: Delete your comment about me just wanting to bypass the comment privilege and I will delete my answer.